# Hailstone Sequence in C

Tags: c, function, sequence

I'm taking a course in C (it's my first week) and I need to write a program that prints out sequences of hailstone numbers.
I'm expected to build a function to do that.

The next number gets printed out but that's it. For example when I enter 58, I get 29. But I'd like to print out a whole sequence of 9 next numbers.

Please, if you could guide in the right direction, I'd be eternally grateful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Hailstone (int n)
{
  if (n % 2 == 0) {
    return n /= 2;
  }
  else {
    return n = 3 * n + 1;
  }
  return n;
}

int main (void)
{
  int start, result;

  printf("Input a number: ");
  scanf("%d", &start);
  result = Hailstone(start);

  printf("%d\n", result);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: you need to *loop* until the result is 1.

Comment: `while(result != 1) ... `

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to *iterate*. You don't need the `result` variable; you just plug in the new value:

```
while (start > 1) {
     start = Hailstone(start);
     printf ("%d\n", start);
}
```

There's a bit more that could be improved, e.g. the `return n;` is unreachable and the assignments to `n` are useless:

```
int Hailstone (int n)
{
  if (n % 2 == 0) {
    return n / 2;
  }
  else {
    return 3 * n + 1;
  }
}
```

If you want to hand in a pro C version of `Hailstone()` you could even write it as

```
int Hailstone (int n)
{
   return n % 2 ? 3 * n + 1 : n / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see, in your program, you are trying to return only a single value to the main..Hence to print all the numbers just write a loop as below..

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int Hailstone(int n)
{
if(n % 2 == 0) {
return n /=2;
}
else {
return n = (3 * n) + 1;
}
 }

int main (void)
{
int start;

 printf("Input a number: ");
scanf("%d", &start);
while(start!=1)
{
  start = Hailstone(start);
printf("%d\n", start);
}
}
```